# Handling admin rights in mixed user/admin windows app

Tags: windows, security, mfc, uac

My MFC app usually runs with admin rights, however, there is one operation which needs admin privileges (activation of the software where the status must be saved to HKLM).

For now, I created two .exe files: The ordinary app and "Activation.exe" which must run as admin and has requestedExecutionLevel=requireAdministrator in the Manifest. The activation is started with a button which makes ShellExecute(Activation.exe).

However, both applications share lots of code so I would like to merge the two exe into one exe. But how do I make sure then that specific parts of the code are executed with admin privileges? This method should/must be compatible down to NT4.

One idea is to integrate the functionality of Activation.exe in the main exe using a switch (e.g. "myapp.exe -activate"). A small bootstrapper makes sure that it can only run as admin (requireAdministrator in Manifest) and does nothing more than ShellExec(myapp.exe -activate). But is this really the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's the best way (no-one answered) but I did that now :) The bootstrapper has just requireAdministrator in the Manifest and does a ShellExecute to the main executeable with switch "/Activate" ...

Answer (score 0):

I would typically use a call to `ShellExecuteEx` with a verb of `runas` to launch any executable as administrator, even if it's manifested `asInvoker`.

Note that on systems where UAC has been disabled, the resulting launch may not receive administrator privileges; I believe this caveat also applies to the approach of launching an exe manifested `requireAdministrator`.